# Windows 7 not visible in GRUB menu after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the same partition (C:/) in which I had Windows 7 installed. After installation of ubuntu, I see Ubuntu boot options in the grub, along with FreeDOS (FreeDOS shows up for my other 2 partitions, D:/ and E:/, my PC had initially come with FreeDOS and I had installed Windows7 to it) and there is no Windows 7 option.

However my Windows data of C: drive is still visible in Ubuntu as "140 GB Volume" with all the previous data present. 
Is there a way in which I can recover the Windows 7?

I am providing the procedure I used in installing Ubuntu, and believe the problem would have happened due to the partitioning option

1. I selected "Do something else" and not "Install Ubuntu along with Windows"
2. Selected the same partition in which there was Windows (C:/)
3. Gave it 40 GB of space, there was 70 GB free space in the partition.
   No other step I performed which I feel could have caused the problem. Please help me out.

I also performed sudo update-grub, but it still lists only linux and freedos systems, and no Windows updates.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal using `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T` and run this command:

```
sudo update-grub | tee ~/update-grub.txt
```

You will need to type in your password. After that runs, try restarting. If it still doesn't work, give us the contents of the file called `update-grub.txt` located in your home directory.

If it doesn't work please read this post on Ubuntu forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602835

or follow these steps:

> try running this in a terminal to see if you have os-prober:
>
> ```
> sudo os-prober
> ```
>
> If you get a message saying that it isn't installed:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install os-prober
> ```
>
> If it runs, make sure the 30_os-prober file is executable. This is the
>   file that actually looks for Windows when you run "update-grub".
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
> ```
>
> Then try updating Grub again. If it finds Windows, you will see a
>   message in the terminal as the command runs. Or after you can see the
>   menu entries without booting by running this:
>
> ```
> grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
> ```

Hope it help

Comment: Here is the log:                                                                                                             pankit@led-ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub | tee ~/update-grub.txt
[sudo] password for pankit: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sda1
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sda2

Comment: hey piotrek, thanks for the help :) however, i am still not able to view Windows :( I followed all the steps provided, but still dint show up Windows. I pasted the results for the grub update above. I also ran this command (sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober) and followed it with grub update, but no change and got the same result. Based on that link you provided, the user ended up reinstalling Windows. Does it seem like the same situation for me?